# How To Cast An Inherited Encapsulated Property To Expose Methods Of Subclass - Java

Tags: java, eclipse, inheritance, casting, decorator

In Java I have an abstract base class, let's say `WrapX`, which contains a property of a type, say `X` (think Decorator DP). This class presents a method to call a specific method on the encapsulated `X`:

```
public abstract class WrapX{

  protected X instance;

  public WrapX(X x){
     this.instance = x;
  }

  public void foo(){
       instance.foo();
  }

}

public class X {

   public void foo(){
       System.out.println("foo");
   }
}
```

There is then a class called `Y` that extends from `X` and provides an additional method:

```
public class Y extends X {

  public void bar(){
     System.out.println("bar");
  }
}
```

Then naturally I have created `WrapY` that can be used as a decorated type over the type `Y`:

```
public class WrapY extends WrapX{

  ...

  public void bar(){
    instance.bar();
  }

}
```

So herein lies the issue. `WrapY` has inherited the `instance` property of type `X` from its parent `WrapX`. As far as Eclipse is concerned, `instance` is of type `X` and so will complain that it contains no method `.bar()`.

Fair enough of course, but how then in this subclass can we implicitly cast the `instance` to an `instance` of `Y` (a valid subclass of the initial type `X`)... WITHOUT the need for explicit cast ascriptions littering the code, or variable shadowing?

If I just had this in the constructor:

```
public WrapY(Y y){
 this.instance = y;
}
```

Eclipse still complains that `.bar()` is not a method of type `X` because I guess it cannot infer for certain that `WrapY(Y y)` will be used prior to construct the `WrapY` instance:

```
public void bar(){
        instance.bar(); // ERROR
      }
```

Here is the current approach I have, littered with casts:

```
public WrapY(Y y){
 (Y)instance = y;
}

public void bar(){
  ((Y)instance).bar();
}
```

I haven't come across this particular type of architectural problem in my experience before, file it under 'Decorator-Based-Inheritance-Type-Casting'(!)... Please enlighten me as to how I can model this in a better way.

Another issue is that, if in future someone extends `WrapY`, the type of instance their class inherits will be the natural (uncasted) type of `X`, when they may reasonably assume it should be of type `Y`.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make your Wrap class generic, for example:

```
public abstract class Wrap<T extends X>{

    protected T instance;

    public Wrap(T x){
        this.instance = x;
    }

    public void foo(){
       instance.foo();
    }
}



public final class WrapY extends Wrap<Y> {

    public WrapY(Y y) {
        super(y);
    }

    public void bar(){
        instance.bar();
    }
}
```

Then for instances of `WrapY`, `instance` will be a `Y`.

---

Update:
If you want to inherit from WrapY, too (and address your last issue of the wrapped type being the most appropriate), do:

```
public class WrapY<U extends Y> extends Wrap<U> {

    public WrapY(U y) {
        super(y);
    }

    public void bar(){
        instance.bar();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I like this idea. However, if I added `WrapZ` which extended from `WrapY extends WrapX<Y>`, then T would still be of type `Y` in `WrapZ`. If I have `WrapZ extends WrapX<Z>` then `WrapZ` will not be in the correct place in the inheritance hierarchy, ie. it won't inherit from `WrapY` (and so won't have inherited methods/properties from `WrapY`. How would you solve this?  Do I need to make all classes generic? eg. `WrapY<T extends Y> extends WrapX<Y>` so that I can have `WrapZ extends WrapY<Z>`? Thanks

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much, this is much cleaner than my current implementation. Especially, given that some classes have rather a lot of methods! Out of interest though, if WrapY is final, I can't extend from it? Does it need to be final?

Comment: @HodeCode: sorry 'bout the copy&paste-error: in the second case, you generify WrapY to be able to inherit from it - so final didn't make much sense.

Comment: @DaveBall no worries, I suspected as much! Thanks very much for contributing to MattR's great solution